# why is my hex string not behaving like a string?

Tags: python, hex

my purpose here is to turn a small file into a qrcode.
So I used binascii.hexlify() to get the hexadecimal of the file.

With pillow I will then build the qr code, this qr code will be read by an other script that will turn it back into a file.

```
import binascii

with open(r"D:\test.png", 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
hexstr = str(binascii.hexlify(content))
#print(hexstr)
print(hexstr[:5])
```

the weird thing here is that the hexstr is `64eded8d8d8d6ad3bcefd7a616864b4aea169786434393975eecb73a1b896cae4e80da592d7dcf2...` but the `hexstr[:5]` is `b'895` (i was expecting `64ede`)

why is that?

Thanks.

ps : I'm using python 3.6x64 on a windows 10 machine

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't overwriting the value of `hexstr` somewhere?  PNG files start with a standard header `b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n'` which is `'89504e470d0a1a0a'` as a hexadecimal string.

Comment: yes, the snippet is the code that i'm running

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting b'895, but when you run `hexstr = str(binascii.hexlify(content)` it gives hexstr the value `"b'64ede...'"`.  The string representation of the bytes sequence includes the `b'` prefix.  I think what you want is `hexstr = binascii.hexlify(content).decode()`.  This will decode the binary string into the corresponding ascii.

```
import binascii

with open(r"D:\test.png", 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
hexstr = binascii.hexlify(content).decode()
#print(hexstr)
print(hexstr[:5])
```

Comment: .decode() gives me a different string : `052564eded8d8d8d6ad3bcefd7a616864b4aea169786434393975eecb73a1b896cae4e80da592d7dcf2ced2657efe01fd83432289542896f4f4f6bb79...`

Comment: ah it's the same with 0525 as a prefix, why is that?

Comment: and slicing it this way hexstr[:5] gives `89504` even weirder

Comment: Yeah, that's strange.  Maybe try adding 'ascii' as an argument to your decode function?

Comment: same thing with ascii

Comment: Just to take the file part out of the equation, do you get the same thing with this:
```import binascii


content = binascii.unhexlify(b'64eded8d8d8d6ad3bcefd7a616864b4aea169786434393975eecb73a1b896cae4e80da592d7dcf')
hexstr = binascii.hexlify(content).decode('ascii')
print(hexstr)
print(hexstr[:5])
```

Comment: I get the same thing with your code, somehow it gets strange only when reading an actual file, if you must know, I'm reading a phone screenshot stored as a png

Comment: Some things to try I guess:  1) Try slicing content before you hexlify it, just to see if it makes a difference.  2) Try 'utf-8' as the decoding argument.

Comment: utf8 full string : ed8d8d8d6ad3bcefd7a616864b4aea169786434393975eecb73a1b896cae4e80da592.....
slicing after hexifly: 89504
utf8 : slicing before hexifly : 89504e470d

Comment: I chekced with an hexadecimal editor, the file starts with `89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 00 00 00 0D 49 48` so the full string is actually wrong, that is weird